# IIS not showing up in Windows Component Wizard

Tags: iis, windows-xp

The system in question is running Windows XP Professional SP 3. The Windows Component Wizard does not list IIS as an option to install. Actually their list looks a lot like the list of components I have available on my netbook running XP Home.

I don't know much about the computer in question, I'm just trying to help someone who needs to install IIS. As far as I know the computer's always been running XP Professional (as opposed to having been upgraded from Home or something...).

Any ideas? I'm stumped, and haven't had any luck with google or searching this site.

Answer (score 2):

I assume Windows is installed in C Drive. It looks like IIS component is hidden from being shown up in 'Add & Remove Windows Components'.

1. Create a backup of "C:\WINDOWS\inf\sysoc.inf".
2. Open C:\WINDOWS\inf\sysoc.inf.
3. Change "iis=iis.dll,OcEntry,iis.inf,hide,7" to "iis=iis.dll,OcEntry,iis.inf,,7"
   Basically search for IIS keyword in sysoc.inf & remove the word "hide". DO NOT REMOVE the comma besides it.

Then after successfully installing IIS, if you want to install ASP.NET,
1. Open cmd rompt.
2. Change drive to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
3. type 'aspnet_regiis.exe -i'

Comment: wow. Why would they purposefully hide this option?

Comment: @Jweede Most corporate computers have IIS disabled and hidden by default for security reasons.

Comment: Wow. This can be a real culture shock coming from Linux.

Comment: Sweet, saved me tons of time.
Thanks.